# [_UISnapshotWindow actualSceneBounds]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native

I am getting crash in iOS(react native app) : ***[_UISnapshotWindow actualSceneBounds]: unrecognized selector***

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException

> 0  CoreFoundation                 0x12a654 __exceptionPreprocess
>
> 1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x5bcc objc_exception_throw
>
> 2  CoreFoundation                 0x2edd8 -[NSOrderedSet
> initWithSet:copyItems:]
>
> 3  UIKitCore                      0xa5cb24 -[UIResponder
> doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
>
> 4  CoreFoundation                 0x12e7f8 ***forwarding***
>
> 5  CoreFoundation                 0x13071c _CF_forwarding_prep_0
>
> 6  UIKitCore                      0x91b5f8 -[UIUndoGestureInteraction
> didMoveToView:]
>
> 7  UIKitCore                      0xee0960 _setInteractionView
>
> 8  UIKitCore                      0xee083c -[UIView(Dragging)
> addInteraction:]
>
> 9  UIKitCore                      0xcb2dcc
> -[UIEditingOverlayViewController _addInteractions]
>
> 10 UIKitCore                      0x3f0814 -[UIViewController
> _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]
>
> 11 UIKitCore                      0x3f0c34 __52-[UIViewController
> _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]_block_invoke
>
> 12 CoreFoundation                 0xfdce0
> **NSARRAY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK**
>
> 13 CoreFoundation                 0x270c -[__NSArrayI
> enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]
>
> 14 UIKitCore                      0x3f09c0 -[UIViewController
> _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]
>
> 15 UIKitCore                      0x3f2a8c __64-[UIViewController
> viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]_block_invoke
>
> 16 UIKitCore                      0x3f1854 -[UIViewController
> _executeAfterAppearanceBlock]
>
> 17 UIKitCore                      0xa37c10
> _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks
>
> 18 UIKitCore                      0xa274ac
> _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks
>
> 19 UIKitCore                      0xa57990 _afterCACommitHandler
>
> 20 CoreFoundation                 0xa7f2c
> **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION**
>
> 21 CoreFoundation                 0xa2e20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
>
> 22 CoreFoundation                 0xa329c __CFRunLoopRun
>
> 23 CoreFoundation                 0xa2ba8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
>
> 24 GraphicsServices               0x3344 GSEventRunModal
>
> 25 UIKitCore                      0xa2e3e4 UIApplicationMain

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Please provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your application code, so others can reproduce the problem on their side.

Comment: did you find any solution or how to reproduce it?